# R Barplot Animation Truncated bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, gif, gganimate

I wanted to animate my barplot but when I try to do so I always get the bars 'truncated' in the animation. This is because the png images show truncated bars and it is not due to the gif "compiler".
The data comes from this website --> https://www.kaggle.com/gregorut/videogamesales

Could you help me with this? Thank you!

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)
    library(gganimate)
    library(gifski)
    
    vg = read.csv("yourpath/vgsales.csv")
    vg$Year = as.numeric(vg$Year) #transform to numeric
    vg = vg[!is.na(vg$Year),] #filter out NA rows
    vg_3 = vg_2[vg_2$Publisher=='Nintendo',]  #account only for Nintendo
    
    #create an animation barplot
    theme_set(
      theme_bw() + 
        theme(legend.position = "top")
      )
    
    myplot = ggplot(vg_3, aes(x=Genre, y=Global_Sales, size = Global_Sales, color = Genre)) +
        geom_point(alpha=0.5)+
        scale_size(range = c(0.2, 11)) +
       labs(title = 'Year: {frame_time}', x = 'Publishers', y = 'Sales') +
       transition_time(Year) +
       ease_aes('linear')
    
    animate(myplot, duration = 9, fps = 25, width = 900, height = 700, renderer = gifski_renderer())
    anim_save("output.gif")
```

Comment: Hi Andrea. Can you explain what you mean by truncated? Also, you say this is a bar plot, but it is a dot plot. Is that intentional? Please try to describe in detail what is wrong with your animation and what you would like improved.

Comment: Hello Allan, it is a dot plot but the code lets it visualize as if it was a barplot. I have created here a GIF of the animation that I get and you can see the "truncated" bars I mean --> https://i.imgur.com/MjbHwFG.gif